# How to kill background music.

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I am going to create music player that play the mp3 files in background. I put play pause stop button in my app. Everything is working fine till i again start my application. Like if i again start my app after playing music from my app. Then both the files will play in background. i am using

```
          private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

so, a new object is created every time. How can i stop my previous playing file before starting new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options.

1. Keep player in static variable. So you create player player only when you start application first time.
2. Run player as background service. This way you can manipulate it by intents. I think it's preferred option though it's more complex. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices).

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it from [Here](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion).Take a look.

Comment: i am not playing music from my raw files. I am trying to play music of my sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the state diagram of MediaPlayer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Maybe you have to stop() and then release() the MediaPlayer object when you finish or pause your application.